# How can I get Google Chrome to show my home page whenever a new tab is opened?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs, homepage

Using the latest Chrome stable version, is there a way either, by editing some config file or via an extension, that will allow me to specify that my home page be opened each time I click the NEW TAB button?

I'd prefer my homepage open rather than the Speed Dial interface - it's a local html file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[New Tab Redirect](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna) is an extension that does exactly what you want.